# deliver application on the appstore : stuck at validation step

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

I am about to deliver an application on the App Store with an "Ad Hoc" provisioning profile (generated from a valid certificate in the apple developer center).
I have to specify that the xcode project file was generated by "phonegap".
Never the less I archived the application from Product/archive) and moved to the following steps consisting in validating the application.

xcode fails and suggest to download identities : I did proceed but xcode failed  pretending "No identities are available for signing".
"An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded"

At this step I have the choice 
+ download identities
+ import developer profile (which I don't know what it is - probably some certificate from an other machine in case i d like to used it)

First choice failed miserably as before and second is a dead end.

Any idea's what I should be doing ?

Comment: You can't deliver to the app store with an Ad hoc profile, you need a distribution profile

Comment: Have a google and you'll find a solution. I had this problem too and stumbled across a solution but can't for the life of me remember where.

Comment: Ah! Missed the ad-hoc part. Well I had a very similar issue trying to push to the app store for an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't give a link-only answer, but it is necessary in this case. You can't use an Ad hoc profile to deliver to the app store. You need a distribution profile.

Please follow Apple's steps to achieve this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html

Comment: @pascalsautot yes it can be built with one but it can't be delivered to the app store built against it

Answer (score 1):

You need to have distribution profile with iOS app store submission (which you can acquire if you are the Agent) and then upload the binary.